# one sheet from each workbook need to be saved as CSV

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have two folders as 2015 and 2016, In each folder, there are 12 sub folders as months and each month folder has many excel files. So for example from 2015 folder - > Aug 15 folder - > PC Aug15.xlsb - > Data(Sheet name)
I need this sheet to get exported as CSV and saved as Aug15.CSV in a new path.

This way I need data from Aug 15 - Jul 16. How can I do that. Please help

Trying to use below code, but dont know how i speicfy that I just need sheet named "Data"

```
Sub SaveToCSVs()
    Dim fDir As String
    Dim wB As Workbook
    Dim wS As Worksheet
    Dim fPath As String
    Dim sPath As String
    fPath = "C:\temp\pydev\"
    sPath = "C:\temp\"
    fDir = Dir(fPath)
    Do While (fDir <> "")
        If Right(fDir, 4) = ".xls" Or Right(fDir, 5) = ".xlsx" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Set wB = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fDir)
            For Each wS In wB.Sheets
                wS.SaveAs sPath & wS.Name, xlCSV
            Next wS
            wB.Close False
            Set wB = Nothing
        End If
        fDir = Dir
        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I actually didnot write on my own, but I took help from below code

Comment: Sub SaveToCSVs()
    Dim fDir As String
    Dim wB As Workbook
    Dim wS As Worksheet
    Dim fPath As String
    Dim sPath As String
    fPath = "C:\temp\pydev\"
    sPath = "C:\temp\"
    fDir = Dir(fPath)
    Do While (fDir <> "")
        If Right(fDir, 4) = ".xls" Or Right(fDir, 5) = ".xlsx" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Set wB = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fDir)
            For Each wS In wB.Sheets
            wS.SaveAs sPath & wS.Name, xlCSV
     Next wS
            wB.Close False
   Set wB = Nothing
End If
  fDir = Dir
 On Error GoTo 0
 Loop
End Sub

Comment: I dont know how to write above in a proper format here.. I am new to this

Answer (score 0):

I Understand that your code is correctly reading all files from the target folder, the problem is that you only want to extract one `Sheet` named `Data` from each file, so if that is the case try this:

**EDIT TO INCLUDE EXTRACTION OF SELECTED COLUMNS ONLY!**

**Method: Copying Target Worksheet**

```
Sub SaveToCSVs()
Const kWshName As String = "Data"
Dim sPathInp As String, sPathOut As String
Dim sPathFile As String, sCsvFile As String
Dim WbkSrc As Workbook, WshSrc As Worksheet
Dim WbkCsv As Workbook, WshCsv As Worksheet
Dim rData As Range

    sPathInp = "C:\temp\pydev\"
    sPathOut = "C:\temp\"
    sPathFile = Dir(sPathInp)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Do While (sPathFile <> "")
        If Right(sPathFile, 4) = ".xls" Or Right(sPathFile, 5) = ".xlsx" Then

            Rem Initialize Objects
            Set WbkSrc = Nothing
            Set WshSrc = Nothing

            Rem Set Objects
            On Error Resume Next
            Set WbkSrc = Workbooks.Open(sPathInp & sPathFile)
            If Not (WbkSrc Is Nothing) Then
                Set WshSrc = WbkSrc.Sheets(kWshName)

                If Not (WshSrc Is Nothing) Then
                    On Error GoTo 0

                    Rem Set Csv Filename
                    sCsvFile = Left(sPathFile, -1 + InStrRev(sPathFile, "."))
                    sCsvFile = sCsvFile & " - " & kWshName

                    Rem Calculate, Unhide Rows & Columns & Copy Data Sheet
                    With WshSrc
                        .Calculate
                        .Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                        .Copy
                    End With
                    Set WshCsv = ActiveSheet

                    Rem Delete All Other Columns
                    With Range(WshCsv.Cells(1), WshCsv.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
                        .Value = .Value
                        Set rData = Union(Columns("A"), Columns("P"), Columns("AC"))
                        rData.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireColumn.Delete
                        rData.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    End With

                    Rem Save as Csv
                    WshCsv.SaveAs Filename:=sPathOut & sCsvFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV
                    WshCsv.Parent.Close
                    WbkSrc.Close

        End If: End If: End If

        sPathFile = Dir
        On Error GoTo 0

    Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    End Sub
```

**Method: Opening Workbook as ReadOnly**

```
Sub SaveToCSVs()
Const kWshName As String = "Data"
Dim sPathInp As String
Dim sPathOut As String
Dim sPathFile As String
Dim sCsvFile As String
Dim WbkSrc As Workbook
Dim WshSrc As Worksheet
Dim rData As Range

    sPathInp = "C:\temp\pydev\"
    sPathOut = "C:\temp\"
    sPathFile = Dir(sPathInp)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Do While (sPathFile <> "")
        If Right(sPathFile, 4) = ".xls" Or Right(sPathFile, 5) = ".xlsx" Then

            Rem Initialize Objects
            Set WbkSrc = Nothing
            Set WshSrc = Nothing

            Rem Set Objects
            On Error Resume Next
            Set WbkSrc = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sPathInp & sPathFile, ReadOnly:=True)
            If Not (WbkSrc Is Nothing) Then
                Set WshSrc = WbkSrc.Sheets(kWshName)

                If Not (WshSrc Is Nothing) Then
                    On Error GoTo 0

                    Rem Set Csv Filename
                    sCsvFile = Left(sPathFile, -1 + InStrRev(sPathFile, "."))
                    sCsvFile = sCsvFile & " - " & kWshName

                    Rem Calculate, Unhide Rows & Columns & Copy Data Sheet
                    With WshSrc
                        .Calculate
                        .Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

                        Rem Delete All Other Columns
                        With Range(.Cells(1), .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
                            .Value = .Value
                            Set rData = Union(Columns("A"), Columns("P"), Columns("AC"))
                            rData.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireColumn.Delete
                            rData.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

                    End With: End With

                    Rem Save as Csv
                    WshSrc.SaveAs Filename:=sPathOut & sCsvFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV
                    WbkSrc.Close

        End If: End If: End If

        sPathFile = Dir
        On Error GoTo 0

    Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any way I can keep only column A, P and AC in these CSV?

Comment: Also won't the above code save all files with one name?